# iOS react native app does not update from CodePush server

Tags: ios, react-native, code-push

I've followed the instructions to set up CodePush properly.  First, I push to AppCenter:

```
$ appcenter codepush release-react -a myUser/appName -d Production
Detecting ios app version:

Using the target binary version value "1.0" from "ios/reactnative/Info.plist".

Running "react-native bundle" command:

node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --assets-dest /var/folders/gy/737c70fj7tq3pwdw758glxz00000gp/T/code-push118924-95814-1e6qqdj.df3g/CodePush --bundle-output /var/folders/gy/737c70fj7tq3pwdw758glxz00000gp/T/code-push118924-95814-1e6qqdj.df3g/CodePush/main.jsbundle --dev false --entry-file index.js --platform ios
Loading dependency graph, done.
bundle: Writing bundle output to: /var/folders/gy/737c70fj7tq3pwdw758glxz00000gp/T/code-push118924-95814-1e6qqdj.df3g/CodePush/main.jsbundle
bundle: Done writing bundle output
bundle: Copying 6 asset files
bundle: Done copying assets

Releasing update contents to CodePush:

Successfully released an update containing the "/var/folders/gy/737c70fj7tq3pwdw758glxz00000gp/T/code-push118924-95814-1e6qqdj.df3g/CodePush" directory to the "Production" deployment of the "appName" app.
```

Second, I go to the AppCenter website, select the successfully pushed version, and do a force roll out to every app.

I've tried to restart the app, reinstall the app, etc...but the app does not update from CodePush servers.

In my XCode console, I see:

```
loading - codepush2018-10-24 12:10:10.837955+0200 reactnative[5546:3916480] 
[CodePush] Loading JS bundle from file:///Users/myUser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4E7D0B07-B6B2-4D3C-B5B8-F28F3DA47077/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/081FD17C-B182-488D-B2D1-C786A3B25AAB/reactnative.app/main.jsbundle
```

Does this mean that CodePush is loading from *local*?

I believe I am running the `release` scheme correctly:

[image: release mode]

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        codePush.sync({
            updateDialog: true,
            installMode: codePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE
        });
    }
    render(){
        return <Main screenProps={this.props} />
    }
}
const codePushOptions = { checkFrequency: codePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_RESUME };
const ConnectedApp = codePush(codePushOptions)(connect(state => state)(App))

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(auth => {
    if(auth){
        store.dispatch(setUser(auth))
    }else{
        store.dispatch(logout())
    }
})

export default () => (
    <Provider store={store}> 
        <ConnectedApp />
    </Provider>
)
```

I also do not see the `updateDialog: true` when App mounts.

Comment: Can you also check the CodePushKey in your `.xcodeproj` file is similar to what you see from their cli code-push deployment `code-push deployment list "AppName" -k `

Comment: Do you use [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/setup-ios.md) guides?

Comment: @PritishVaidya you are correct. It was the key difference. Can you write your comment as an answer so I can give you the bounty? Thank you.

Comment: Sure, I'll add an answer and a possible workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Code Push keys must be **same** to the *environment* to which the application is being released and the one to which the application is built in order to receive the changes.

There are two possible solutions in order to avoid this conflict.

- Define separate Build Schemes.
- Add a custom script that changes Code Push keys with the environment change.

## Build Schemes / Types

### Android

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        releaseStaging {
            ...
            buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '"<INSERT_STAGING_KEY>"'
            ...
        }
        release {
            ...
            buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '"<INSERT_PRODUCTION_KEY>"'
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/multi-deployment-testing-android.md)

In the `android/app/build.gradle` you can defined the various `buildTypes` and build the app based on it

### IOS

Under the **Info** tab click the `+` button within `Configurations` and `Duplicate "Release" Configuration` and set its name to `Staging`

Now you can configure the `User Defined Settings` and define a new setting `CODEPUSH_KEY` and set `${CODEPUSH_KEY}` variable to the different schemes.

Elaborated steps are explained here: [Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/blob/master/docs/multi-deployment-testing-ios.md)

## Custom Script

Alternatively, if you don't want to add more *Build Schemes / Types*, you can add a custom script that changes keys based on the environment.

### change-environment.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#################################
# Change the environment variable
#################################

environment=$1
# Read Directory Path
parent_path=$( cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" ; pwd -P )
cd "$parent_path"
rm ../.env
# Set NODE_ENV in your .env file based on the script
echo "NODE_ENV=${environment}" > ../.env


#################################
# Change the code push key
#################################

if [ "$environment" = "staging" ]
then
    echo "Change Code Push Key - Staging"
    sed -i '' -E 's/CODEPUSH_KEY ?= ?".+"/CODEPUSH_KEY = "${YOUR_STAGING_IOS_CODEPUSH_KEY}"/' ../ios/YourProj.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
    sed -i '' -E 's/buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '\''".+"'\''/buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '\''"${YOUR_STAGING_ANDROID_CODEPUSH_KEY}"'\''/' ../android/app/build.gradle
elif [ "$environment" = "production" ]
then
    echo "Change Code Push Key - Production"
    sed -i '' -E 's/CODEPUSH_KEY ?= ?".+"/CODEPUSH_KEY = "${YOUR_PRODUCTION_IOS_CODEPUSH_KEY}"/' ../ios/YourProj.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
    sed -i '' -E 's/buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '\''".+"'\''/buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '\''"${YOUR_PRODUCTION_ANDROID_CODEPUSH_KEY}"'\''/' ../android/app/build.gradle
fi
```

Now you can run `.${SCRIPT_PATH}/change-environment.sh ${ENV}`

Example: `./change-environment.sh staging`

This script changes the `buildConfigField` in android `buildTypes` and `CODEPUSH_KEY` **User Defined Settings** to the pre defined schemes in ios.

It would be convenient combine this script with the react native's packager start command in your `package.json`

```
"start": "./change-environment.sh development && node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
"start:staging": "./change-environment.sh staging && node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
"start:production": "./change-environment.sh production && node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CodePush` is not loading from exactly, it downloads the bundle from the `CodePush` server. So path you have seen is a path part of your simulator's file system.

Please refer here to know how to set deployment target

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/react-native